# How to pass an int value to another class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing a Int value to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937066/passing-a-int-value-to-another-class)

I have been trying to get "getExtra" to work but without success,  I have a listview with 4 choices which launch a webpage within a webView class, when the user selects the option lets say option 3 I want to pass the value of 3 to the webView class so that it will load the correct webpage, at the moment all I get is errors, can somebody help with where I am going wrong.

This is my intent

```
         if (position == 0)  {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, official.class);
                startActivity(intent);intent.putExtra(webb = 3);}
```

This is the getextras code in the official class with the webpages I want to load

```
Bundle webb = getIntent().getExtras(),
```

variableGet = webb.getInt(webb);

```
if (webb == 2)      mWebView.loadUrl("http://bcafc.livewwware.co.uk/viewforum.php?f=7&sid=009c462b00069f307ef6dcd09e747f7c");
  if (webb == 3)   mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It appears as though you're starting the activity with the intent before putting the extra. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I've changed this it makes no difference in terms of errors

Comment: You really should rethink programming if you're having issues with this. 1.) you're setting the extra after starting the activity. 2.) you're using `web == 2` when web is a `Bundle`.

Comment: Falmarri. I apologise if this is a problem for you I am merely learning and I find opinions like this neither helpful nor constructive, I see this is obviously easy for you I have been programming for weeks and still struggle with these because they differ greatly from the sort of programming language I'm used to.

Answer (score 3):

"if (position == 0)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, official.class);
  startActivity(intent);intent.putExtra(webb = 3);
}"

You have the right idea. You want to initialize your intent before starting your activity and get/set the parameter something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, official.class);
Intent.putExtra("weburl", 3);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the activity you started, you get "weburl" like this:

```
int number = getIntent().getIntExtra("weburl", 0);
```

if (number == 2)
  mWebView.loadUrl("http://bcafc.....");
else if (number == 3)
  mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.bbc..");

Comment: Thank you, I think my problem is I think in Visual basic language far too much.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, you'll probably need to post more code in order to have a helpful answer.  At a minimum though, your 1st code block should be rewritten as:

```
if (position == 0)  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, official.class);
    webb = 3;
    intent.putExtra("webb", webb);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And to retrieve, something like:

```
int webb = getIntent().getIntExtra("webb", -1);
```

You could probably continue use the bundles as you have, but I'm surprised the 1st code block compiles for you and I think this code would be cleaner to understand.  Regardless, you need to set the webb value before you start the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, official.class);
intent.putExtra("webb", 3);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
int webb = extras.getInt("webb");
```