# Passing a int value from one class to another

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing a Int value to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937066/passing-a-int-value-to-another-class)

I have been trying to get "getExtra" to work but without success, I have a listview with 4 choices which launch a webpage within a webView class, when the user selects the option lets say option 3 I want to pass the value of 3 to the webView class so that it will load the correct webpage, at the moment I get no errors, but the app force closes when I select the option, could this be due to having to announce this in the manifest? can somebody help with where I am going wrong.

This is my intent

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

         if (position == 0)  {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, official.class);
         intent.putExtra("weburl", 3);

         startActivity(intent);}
```

This is the official class:

```
public class official extends Activity {

int number = getIntent().getIntExtra("weburl", 0);

   @Override

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {

        mWebView.goBack();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser1);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

if (number == 2)    mWebView.loadUrl("http://bcafc.livewwware.co.uk");
  if (number == 3)   mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `int number = getIntent().getIntExtra("weburl", 0);` line to onCreate of the official class. If you still get an error, you may want to post the log